# How do I set a variable then call the updated variable in the same function? PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to create a function where I check whether the label has been set. Update the label based on whether it is set or not, then call that updated label in another variable.

```
function update_label() {
  if (empty($label) {
    $label = 'foo';
  } else {
    $label = $label . ' bar';
  }
  $article_meta = $label . ' updated' . time();
}
```

I am checking if the label has been set if not to Populate label as foo. If a label has been set to update with bar after the label. These 2 work.
But then I am trying to update a third field which contains the updated field but it always passes on the original value.

So if the label has been set $article_meta should return 'label bar updated today' but returns 'label updated today'.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Apart from the syntax error (missing `)` at the if), $label will of course never be set in that position - you are in a function scope, but you did not pass $label as a parameter, so where is it supposed to come from? _"But then I am trying to update a third field which contains the updated field but it always passes on the original value."_ - we can not even see here where you would actually be checking on that - the function does not return anything, and there is no output-generating statement either. Please show a _proper_ [mre] of the issue.

Comment: Look up passing parameters by _reference_. BTW, the code example you give is very strange so it's difficult to ascertain exactly what you want: The function has no arguments, so where does $label come from? It also returns nothing? Why not return $article_meta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be the easy fix

```
function update_label(string $label): string {
  if (empty($label)) {
    $label = 'foo';
  } else {
    $label = $label . ' bar';
  }
  return $label . ' updated' . time();
}
```